# Decoding base64 image and uploading it to server with php

Tags: php, base64

I'm passing image as a base64 string from a form. Then I would like to decode it, rename it and upload it to my server folder. I can't get this to work so obviously I'm doing something wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
$image = $_POST['image-data'];//base64 string of a .jpg image passed from form:

$image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);//Getting rid of the start of the string:
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$image = base64_decode($image);

$ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($image, '.'), 1)); //Get extension of image

$lenght = 10;
$image_name = substr(str_shuffle("123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $lenght);

$image_name = $image_name . '.' . $ext; //New image name

$uploaddir = '/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/img/'; //Upload image to server
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $image_name;
move_uploaded_file('$image', $uploadfile);
```

Comment: Why are you converting the file before uploading? More information on how to handle file uploads in php http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: You can not use move_upload_file (you are not uploading any file). Your Image data is present as string. I think you have to create an image from the string resource. GD oder Imagick is your friend ;) Then save the image as file to your 'upload dir'.

Answer (score 1):

Using file put content you can move files to folder

```
$file = $_POST['image-data'];
$pos = strpos($file, ';');
$type = explode(':', substr($file, 0, $pos))[1];
$mime = explode('/', $type);

$pathImage = "path to move file/".time().$mime[1];
$file = substr($file, strpos($file, ',') + 1, strlen($file));
$dataBase64 = base64_decode($file);
file_put_contents($pathImage, $dataBase64);
```

Comment: This looks promising. However I get error message from this line: `$type = explode(':', substr($file, 0, $pos))[1];`